# Custom key-bind functionality in curses

Tags: python-3.x, curses, python-curses, tui

I'm trying to implement some simple text editing functionality in a TUI I'm working on. I'm using the Python wrapper for curses.

Currently what I'm trying to do is associate certain key-binds to a particular function or operation, but unsure of how to do it and the documentation isn't clear. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/curses.html#module-curses.textpad) there are some default keybinds, but what if I wanted to add my own "event" associated with a particular keybind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place to start is by looking at the source code of [`curses.textpad`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/curses/textpad.py) to see how it is implemented.  It's hardcoded, e.g.,

```
    elif ch == curses.ascii.ENQ:                           # ^e
        if self.stripspaces:
            self.win.move(y, self._end_of_line(y))
        else:
            self.win.move(y, self.maxx)
```

It could be rewritten to allow for custom bindings, but keep in mind that at the moment (mid-February 2021), the most recent commit was more than 4 years ago ([December 2016](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/bdf9e0ea7473bcdb7f4c01f4b76db875ec8bc64e#diff-c1ffc176a4a6868de72569b40ff076ecd7a54b1f1166ba89229f33f1eaedb279)).

Comment: So does this mean I'd have to modify source code of curses.textpad and then build it for myself?

Comment: yes - just that (if the changes were generally useful, you might open an issue with the maintainer and improve the upstream source).